# GCCのコンパイラに関して、パスは通っているのにエラーが発生します。

Tags: c++, c, gcc

プログラムはこちらです。

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void){
    printf("Hello world!"); 
    return 0;
}
```

エラーが長かったのでこちらに載せました。
https://pastebin.com/hbZcTR4t

ヘッダファイルがないわけではないということはパスは通っていると思うのですが、解決方法が昨日からいくつかのサイトをはしごしながら考えたり実行しているのですがうまく実行ファイルが得られません。どうかお力を貸していただけないでしょうか？

こちらの方でも回答を求めています。https://teratail.com/questions/119490
まだちゃんとした解決法がわかっていません。どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `_mingw.h`が見つからないといったエラーが発生し、それに対し何らかの対処をしませんでしたか？

Comment: それに関しての対処はしいないというか、_mingw.hはC:\MinGW\includeのヘッダファイルディレクトリに保存されていまして、ユーザー環境変数のINCLUDEにC:\MinGW\includeを、PATHにC:\MinGWを書き加え、システム変数ののINCLUDEにC:\MinGW\includeを、PATHにC:\MinGWを書き加えました。

Comment: PATH 変数ですが、`C:\MinGW` ではなくて `C:\MinGW\bin` という事はないでしょうか？

Comment: システム環境変数のpath変数にはC:\MinGW\binのほうが書いてあります。C:\MinGWにしたほうが良いのでしょうか？ほとんどのサイトでC:\MinGW\binとしていたのでC:\MinGW\binが正解だと思っていました。

Comment: C:\MinGW\binからC:\MinGW にしましたがエラーは消えませんでした。

Comment: プログラムの問題ではなく環境の問題なのは明らかです。OSは何か、どのように GCC を入れたとか、どこからダウンロードしたとか、そういう情報が必要かと思われます。

Comment: インストールし直したところうまくいきました。どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: @ToxinCarnage お疲れ様でした。自己解決した場合、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することができます。是非お願いいたします :)

Comment: どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

インストールしなおしたところ、問題が解決できました。回答していただいた皆様どうもありがとうございました。